# DECRYPTBYASYMKEY() Not Returning Expected Value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I'm playing around with [Asymmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173744.aspx), but I don't understand the results I'm getting when I try to decrypt values.

Why does this:

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY myasymkey 
    WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048 
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '123pass!'; 
GO

SELECT DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('myasymkey'), 
    EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('myasymkey'), 'Greg'), 
    N'123pass!');
GO
```

Produce `0x47726567`? I was expecting it to be `Greg`.

**UPDATE:** I'm dumb, `0x47726567` is `Greg` when converted from `varbinary`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's right - when you encrypt something it's treated as a byte array and is returned as such. 0x47 is G, 72 is r etc.

If you examine the documentation for [DecryptByAsmKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189507.aspx) you'll notice the return type is varbinary with a maximum size of 8,000 bytes. You'll also notice the convert in the example.

So if you are encrypting and decrypting strings you must convert like so

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max),DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('myasymkey'), 
    EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('myasymkey'), 
    'Greg'), 
    N'123pass!'));
```

Also note you need to make sure you're converting to varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) depending on your input. If you tried

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(max),DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('myasymkey'), 
    EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('myasymkey'), 
    'Greg'), 
    N'123pass!'));
```

it would be wrong, as your input of 'Greg' is a varchar.

Answer (score 2):

I think `0x47726567` is `Greg` (in ASCII).

Answer (score 2):

All the encryption functions return varbinary values. You will have to cast the result as varchar.