# Comparing encrypted columns in query

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, security, cryptography

I am trying to fetch username having a specified email from database using SQL query:

```
SELECT [USERNAME] FROM REGTAB WHERE DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('ENKEY'),[EMAIL])=@email
```

But it's showing `NULL` output. Do I need to encrypt the input `@email` before comparing? Will it always yield the same encrypted value for a particular input?

I am using RSA 2048 algorithm.

Comment: [DECRYPTBYASYMKEY() Not Returning Expected Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768144/decryptbyasymkey-not-returning-expected-value)

Comment: @bummi after using `CONVERT()` it's still returning `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shot into the dark since you did not provide the way your key `ENKEY` was created.
From the behavior I'd expect it been created with password and you are not providing the password for DECRYPTBYASYMKEY, which can be called without the third parameter for e.g. Keys using the master key of the database.

```
/*
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY ENKEY 
    WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048 
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Mydummypassword'; 
*/

/*
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password'
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY ENKEY2 
     WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048  

*/

Declare @aValue Varchar(50)
Select @aValue='Test' 

Select DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('ENKEY'),
EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('ENKEY'), @aValue)
) as [WithOutPassword]
,
DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('ENKEY'),
EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('ENKEY'), @aValue)
,N'Mydummypassword') as [WithPassword]

,Case when @aValue=DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('ENKEY'),
EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('ENKEY'), @aValue)
)  then 1 else 0 end as [IdenticWithOutPassword]

,Case when @aValue=DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('ENKEY'),
EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('ENKEY'), @aValue)
,N'Mydummypassword')  then 1 else 0 end as [IdenticWithPassword]
```

will deliver the result:
NULL    0x54657374  0   1

```
Select DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('ENKEY2'),
EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('ENKEY2'), @aValue)
) as [With MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION]

,Case when @aValue=DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('ENKEY2'),
EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('ENKEY2'), @aValue)
)  then 1 else 0 end as [Identic]
```

will deliver the result:
0x54657374  1

Comment: with password and then using `CONVERT()` it's working fine. But I want to hide this password. I don't want it to be visible in query. How can I do it? Please help me as I am newbie to SQL Server Encryption.

Comment: Since I'm not sure what you will need, one easy possible use could be using a encrypted procedure `Alter Procedure P_GetUserforEmail(@email varchar(50)) 
WITH ENCRYPTION as ....` delivering the username for the eMail.